How do switches route ethernet packets - when there are two switches in series between origin and destination?
I would like to introduce my question with the following example:
Let us say we want to sent an ethernet packet from computer A to computer B via a switch

We sent the packet with destination BBB from Computer A to the Switch
The switch only operates on datalink layer. The switch has already a MAC adress table. The switch knows on port 2 is the host MAC BBB so he wil direct the ethernet packet via port 2 to Computer B

So all this makes sense, but please have a look at the second example below.


Let us say we want to sent a ethernet packet from computer A to Computer B in a different configuration: This time Switch #1 and Switch #2 are in between. Both switches only operate only on datalink layer with MAC Adresses

Computer A starts sending the ethernet packet to Computer B
This ist the point where Iam lost. Switch #1 receives the packet and tries to look up BBB on its MAC adress table. But he cannot find BBB because Switch #2 is in between. How does the switch 1 learn that he has to forward the package to port 2 and not to port 3 ??? From my point of view the MAC adress table does not help here. Can somebody please enlight me what step in between is missing?




How do switches route ethernet packets...

Switches (bridges) do not route packets. Routers route packets. Switches bridge frames. A layer-3 packet is the payload of a layer-2 frame.
Switches are layer-2 devices that are bridges that bridge layer-2 frames between links. When a switch receives a frame on a link, it puts the source MAC address and port on which it received the frame into its CAM (Mac address) table, then it looks up the destination MAC address in the table and forwards the frame to the port associated with that MAC address. If it does not find the destination MAC address in the table, it floods the frame to all ports other than the one on which it was received.
A port can have multiple MAC addresses associated with it in the table because the table is indexed by MAC address, not by port. Multiple MAC addresses in the table can have the same port number. You get that when you have a switch-to-switch connections. The port to the other switch will probably be associated with many MAC addresses.

Many thanks for your valueable answer! Appreciated!

One last question to your statement: "...If it does not find the destination MAC address in the table, it floods the frame to all ports..." So flooding sound to me increasing the load on the network, because frames get sent to ports where there is no destination device.
Can the switch #1 somehow learn that destination MAC BBB is on port 2? Or is the flooding procedure continued on and on?

@user96214 MAC addresses and the ports they are located on are automatically learned from each frame's source address.

@Zac67 Ah, okay, thanks for your input. So I guess in my example flooding will stop until Computer 2 sends back a frame to Computer 1 and Switch #1 learns that Computer  2 is reachable on Switch#1/port 2 - multiple mac adresses on one port as Ron Maupin mentioned

@user96214 It is important to understand that initially, Computer A does not know the mac address of computer B. Computer A will send an ARP request first to resolve the destination IP address to a mac address. Layer 2 switches do not contain an ARP table like a layer 3 router does, and therefore the Arp request will get flooded out of all ports on both switches other than the port it was received on. Computer B will then respond to the ARP request letting Computer A know what it's mac address is. During that process both switches will have updated their CAM tables with the ports on which both computer A and computer B's mac addresses reside. The mac address tied to the IP address of computer B will now be in the ARP cache of computer A. So in short, the process of the ARP request will have already updated the CAM tables on both switches and therefore there will be no need to flood the frame to all ports when the switch is looking for the mac address. However, the default timeout for a CAM table entry to expire is 300 seconds and the typical lifetime of an ARP cache entry on a computer can vary, and as such this can effect whether or not an ARP request needs to be sent again or if a frame flood for a mac address will occur.

Of course ARP assumes you are using IPv4, but there are also other protocols that ethernet can carry. For example, IPv6 that does not have broadcast that ARP requires, and it does not use ARP.

Agreed. The assumption is IPv4 is in use regarding my input. Thank you for pointing that out.
